# Animating toolbar with ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, toolbar

currently I have a `Toolbar` and a `ListView` underneath it. I would like to make my content more immersive, and I wish to do this by making the toolbar scroll up out of the screen as you scroll the `ListView`, like the Google Play Store's top charts view. I am using https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView to get when the list is scrolled, but now my question is how do I translate the toolbar as I scroll the list? I don't want to use the `onUpOrCancelMotionEvent()` method because that is only triggered when the user releases his/her finger, no as I scroll. The code I've gotten so far:

```
lv.setScrollViewCallbacks(new ObservableScrollViewCallbacks() {
        int last = -1;

        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(int i, boolean b, boolean b2) {
            if (b2) {
                if (last == -1) {
                    last = i;
                } else {
                    int dy = i - last;

                    if(toolbar.getY() > -TOOLBAR_HEIGHT && dy > 0) {
                        if(toolbar.getY() - dy < -TOOLBAR_HEIGHT)
                            toolbar.setY(-TOOLBAR_HEIGHT);
                        else
                            toolbar.setY(toolbar.getY() - dy);

                        tabs.setY(toolbar.getY() + TOOLBAR_HEIGHT);
                    }else if(toolbar.getY() < 0 && dy < 0) {
                        if (toolbar.getY() - dy > 0)
                            toolbar.setY(0);
                        else
                            toolbar.setY(toolbar.getY() - dy);

                        tabs.setY(toolbar.getY() + TOOLBAR_HEIGHT);
                    }

                    last = i;
                }
            }
        }
        ...
}
```

Now this works, but a white rectangle is rendered where the original toolbar was, like so: http://i.imgur.com/akY7hly.gif (it's a gif).

How I can animate the toolbar with the listview / properly translate the toolbar?

Comment: why dont you set Animation on the `toolbar`?

Comment: Don't use `toolbar.setY()` use `toolbar.setTranslationY()` instead

Comment: Sorry been busy lately

Comment: Will try in a couple hours

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what i mean, when its time for the scrolling

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
                            getBaseContext(), R.anim.push_up_out)
yourtoolbar.startAnimation(anim);
```

*remember to set a listener on your animation and set the Visibility to GONE* that is to clear screen space, but the alpha on the animation will make it gone but fill space

this is **R.anim.push_up_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<translate
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromYDelta="0"
    android:toYDelta="-100%p" />

<alpha
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />

</set>
```